# Add Stripe subscription to customer with PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I retrieve a customer using:

`$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve( $customer_id );`

When I use `$customer->subscriptions->create($array)`, I get an error message saying:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Stripe_Object::create()`

I can add a subscription using `$customer->updateSubscription($array)` and that works fine, but that doesn't allow me to add multiple subscriptions of the same plan to one customer. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here's a print out of $customer:

```
object(Stripe_Customer)[135]
  protected '_apiKey' => string 'sk_test_...' (length=32)
  protected '_values' => 
    array (size=14)
      'id' => string 'cus_...' (length=18)
      'object' => string 'customer' (length=8)
      'created' => int 1415377515
      'livemode' => boolean false
      'description' => null
      'email' => string 'email' (length=25)
      'delinquent' => boolean false
      'metadata' => 
        object(Stripe_Object)[333]
          protected '_apiKey' => string 'sk_test_...' (length=32)
          protected '_values' => 
            array (size=1)
              'user_id' => string '107' (length=3)
          protected '_unsavedValues' => 
            object(Stripe_Util_Set)[334]
              private '_elts' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
          protected '_transientValues' => 
            object(Stripe_Util_Set)[335]
              private '_elts' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
      'subscriptions' => 
        object(Stripe_Object)[336]
          protected '_apiKey' => string 'sk_test_...' (length=32)
          protected '_values' => 
            array (size=5)
              'object' => string 'list' (length=4)
              'total_count' => int 1
              'has_more' => boolean false
              'url' => string '/v1/customers/cus_.../subscriptions' (length=46)
              'data' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => 
                    object(Stripe_Object)[358]
                      protected '_apiKey' => string 'sk_test_...' (length=32)
                      protected '_values' => 
                        array (size=17)
                          'id' => string 'sub_...' (length=18)
                          'plan' => 
                            object(Stripe_Object)[219]
                              protected '_apiKey' => string 'sk_test_...' (length=32)
                              protected '_values' => 
                                array (size=12)
                                  'id' => string 'standard' (length=8)
                                  'interval' => string 'month' (length=5)
                                  'name' => string 'Standard' (length=8)
                                  'created' => int 1414519701
                                  'amount' => int 9900
                                  'currency' => string 'usd' (length=3)
                                  'object' => string 'plan' (length=4)
                                  'livemode' => boolean false
                                  'interval_count' => int 1
                                  'trial_period_days' => int 30
                                  'metadata' => 
                                    array (size=0)
                                      empty
                                  'statement_description' => string 'Charge' (length=9)
                              protected '_unsavedValues' => 
                                object(Stripe_Util_Set)[340]
                                  private '_elts' => 
                                    array (size=0)
                                      empty
                              protected '_transientValues' => 
                                object(Stripe_Util_Set)[249]
                                  private '_elts' => 
                                    array (size=0)
                                      empty
                          'object' => string 'subscription' (length=12)
                          'start' => int 1415381678
                          'status' => string 'trialing' (length=8)
                          'customer' => string 'cus_...' (length=18)
                          'cancel_at_period_end' => boolean false
                          'current_period_start' => int 1415381678
                          'current_period_end' => int 1417973678
                          'ended_at' => null
                          'trial_start' => int 1415381678
                          'trial_end' => int 1417973678
                          'canceled_at' => null
                          'quantity' => int 1
                          'application_fee_percent' => null
                          'discount' => null
                          'metadata' => 
                            array (size=0)
                              empty
                      protected '_unsavedValues' => 
                        object(Stripe_Util_Set)[357]
                          private '_elts' => 
                            array (size=0)
                              empty
                      protected '_transientValues' => 
                        object(Stripe_Util_Set)[343]
                          private '_elts' => 
                            array (size=0)
                              empty
          protected '_unsavedValues' => 
            object(Stripe_Util_Set)[337]
              private '_elts' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
          protected '_transientValues' => 
            object(Stripe_Util_Set)[359]
              private '_elts' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
      'discount' => null
      'account_balance' => int 0
      'currency' => string 'usd' (length=3)
      'cards' => 
        object(Stripe_Object)[107]
          protected '_apiKey' => string 'sk_test_...' (length=32)
          protected '_values' => 
            array (size=5)
              'object' => string 'list' (length=4)
              'total_count' => int 1
              'has_more' => boolean false
              'url' => string '/v1/customers/cus_.../cards' (length=38)
              'data' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => 
                    object(Stripe_Object)[356]
                      protected '_apiKey' => string 'sk_test_...' (length=32)
                      protected '_values' => 
                        array (size=21)
                          'id' => string 'card_...' (length=29)
                          'object' => string 'card' (length=4)
                          'last4' => string '4242' (length=4)
                          'brand' => string 'Visa' (length=4)
                          'funding' => string 'credit' (length=6)
                          'exp_month' => int 12
                          'exp_year' => int 2014
                          'fingerprint' => string '...' (length=16)
                          'country' => string 'US' (length=2)
                          'name' => string 'email' (length=25)
                          'address_line1' => null
                          'address_line2' => null
                          'address_city' => null
                          'address_state' => null
                          'address_zip' => null
                          'address_country' => null
                          'cvc_check' => string 'pass' (length=4)
                          'address_line1_check' => null
                          'address_zip_check' => null
                          'dynamic_last4' => null
                          'customer' => string 'cus_...' (length=18)
                      protected '_unsavedValues' => 
                        object(Stripe_Util_Set)[355]
                          private '_elts' => 
                            array (size=0)
                              empty
                      protected '_transientValues' => 
                        object(Stripe_Util_Set)[64]
                          private '_elts' => 
                            array (size=0)
                              empty
          protected '_unsavedValues' => 
            object(Stripe_Util_Set)[106]
              private '_elts' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
          protected '_transientValues' => 
            object(Stripe_Util_Set)[354]
              private '_elts' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
      'default_card' => string 'card_...' (length=29)
  protected '_unsavedValues' => 
    object(Stripe_Util_Set)[230]
      private '_elts' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  protected '_transientValues' => 
    object(Stripe_Util_Set)[138]
      private '_elts' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Comment: You're calling a method on an object that doesn't exist. Create it, or find out where it really lives and call it appropriately.

Comment: What Stripe version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like that's the case, but that's what the API doc says to do and I can't find an alternate way to do it. https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription

Comment: I'm using Stripe PHP wrapper version 1.17.2

Comment: It's open source. Search the project for a create method and file a bug with their documentation if it's incorrect.

Comment: It sounds like there's an issue with your version of [stripe-php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php).

Comment: Alternatively, your `$customer` object may not actually be pulling any customer data. What happens if you `var_dump($customer)` it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, this is usually how I do it.

Updating the subscription of a customer:

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($customerStripeID);
$customer -> description = "Plan Change";
$customer -> updateSubscription(array('plan' => $planID);
$customer -> save();

OR

$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($customerStripeID);
$subscription = $customer -> subscriptions -> retrieve($customerStripePlanID);
$subscription -> plan = $newPlan;
$subscription -> save();
```

New customer:

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
            'card' => $token,
            'description' => 'New Customer')
            );
$customer->subscriptions->create(array('plan' => $planID));
```

I remember that older code I used suddenly stopped working when I updated my Stripe version. Maybe, if you get the latest one your code will run flawless.

**Edit** not sure why I got voted down. I've been using Stripe a lot lately, and these solutions have been working fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, for me updating is working fine, it's the second call `$customer->subscriptions->create(array('plan'=>$plan_id))` that doesn't work. And updateSubscription() doesn't let you add multiple subscriptions of the same plan, which I need.

Comment: And what happens if you do a print_r of the $customer object?

Comment: Updated my question with the printout.

Comment: Well, try downloading 1.17.3. According to the changelog this has happened:
- * Add support for multiple subscriptions per customer
- * Change internal function names [...]

Comment: What does the array that you try to send to the create method contain?

Comment: Just `array('plan' => $plan)`

Comment: ... and I suppose $plan contains an existing plan, right?

Comment: Yup - I appreciate you asking the obvious questions as I've definitely been there before where I just was overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Okay... I just tried this myself:
`$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve('my-customer-id');
$customer->subscriptions->create(array('plan'=>'newtestplan'));` and it was successful using version 1.17.3. No problems at all. I'm sorry buddy, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I appreciate your help nevertheless.

Comment: Yes, an unused plugin was loading an older version of the API wrapper before the plugin that I was working on get to load it -facepalm-. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi where can i get that customer id, thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @kiranmulmi , sorry for this very late reply. I guess you already figured it out, but in case others have a similar problem. You will find the customer id your customer object. In the above example you do a `var_dump($customer)` and you will get the id (along with a whole bunch of other things).